# what's the magic behind event handler?

Tags: c#, events

What's the magic behind **Control.SizeChanged Event** ? According to MSDN This event is raised if the Size property is changed by either a programmatic modification or user interaction.

But how does the program knows I manually changed the size ----> so that it calls the handler function to do sth..? My guesss is there exists some kind of data binding behind so when size changed the **INotification** interface will be called ?

```
Window.Current.SizeChanged += WindowSizeChanged;
void WindowSizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Size.Width <= 750)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "ColumnarLayout", false);
    }
    else
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "TabularLayout", false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how does the program knows I manually changed the size

You set the size via `Size` property. The property setter triggers the event.

See, for instance,  [How to: Implement Property Change Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)